# JSON streaming in React JS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, stream

I just need to get all JSON parts which is coming from backend side through the JSON stream.

I've found similar solution for Node:

```
var request = require(‘request’);
var JSONStream = require(‘JSONStream’);
var es = require(‘event-stream’);

request(options)
   .pipe(JSONStream.parse(‘*’))
   .pipe(es.map(function(message) {
     handle(message)
   }));
```

but can't find something like this for ReactJS.

Comment: never worked with it, but there's an npm package called "react-json-stream" maybe this could help you?

Comment: Are you trying to use server sent event? If so you can use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) or you can go with `SocketIO` or `WebSockets` if you also need to support older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I've found nice solution for this purpose:
https://davidwalsh.name/streaming-data-fetch-ndjson